# Issues with "MySQL 8" sql statements

Tags: mysql

**I updated to mysql 8 I face issues with creating of the accounts table.**

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS accounts(
    id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT UNIQUE,
    username VARCHAR(30),
    email VARCHAR(100),
    password VARCHAR(255),
    rank VARCHAR(10),
    ban VARCHAR(10),
    token VARCHAR(100),
    created_at VARCHAR(100),
    lastlogin VARCHAR(100)
)
```

The error says me the mistake is on line 6 near

```sql
rank VARCHAR(10),
ban VARCHAR(10),
token VARCHAR(100),
```

Comment: Do you get any error messages?

Comment: Yes I have add it into the post.

Comment: No you haven't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you check the MySQL 8 reserved words - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html

> RANK (R); added in 8.0.2 (reserved)

so you will have to either change the name or enclose it in backticks...

```
`rank` VARCHAR(10),
```

Comment: In general, **always use backticks**, and this is exactly why. Now you have to alter all your code to make it compatible with the newer MySQL. That was avoidable.